# JavaFX - how can I get a TableView to show the strings in an array?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

After trying many different ways, I have not been able to get this TableView to display any strings. Originally, the data was supposed to come from a ResultSet object but, I could not get that work. My latest attempt (below) seems like the most straightforward way to display data but, the strings still will not show.

As you can see, the TableView and ListView are described in an FXML document. The ListView shows it's strings without any problems. Am I missing something?

```
public class AudioPlayerFXMLController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private ListView playList;
@FXML
private TableView playListTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn pathColumn, artistColumn, titleColumn, albumColumn,
        trackNumberColumn, lengthColumn, descriptionColumn,
        ratingColumn, dateColumn, settingColumn, URLColumn, languageColumn,
        nowPlayingColumn, publishedByColumn, encodedByColumn, artworkURLColumn,
        trackIDColumn;

private static final String NEW_PLAYLIST = "New Playlist";
private static final String FRIEND_PLAYLIST = "Friend's Playlist";
private static final String LIBRARY = "Library";
private static ButtonCell bc;
ObservableList<String> observablePlayList;
ObservableList<String> observableListForTableView;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    observablePlayList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    observablePlayList.add(NEW_PLAYLIST);
    observablePlayList.add(FRIEND_PLAYLIST);
    observablePlayList.add(LIBRARY);

    observableListForTableView = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    observableListForTableView.add(NEW_PLAYLIST);
    observableListForTableView.add(FRIEND_PLAYLIST);
    observableListForTableView.add(LIBRARY);

    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "three", "three",
            "three", "three", "three", "three",
            "three", "three", "three", "three", ""
            + "three", "three", "three", "three");

    System.out.println(FXCollections.observableArrayList(values));
    playListTableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(values));
    playList.setItems(observablePlayList);

    playList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
            bc = new ButtonCell();
            return bc;
        }
    });

    playList.setEditable(true);
    playList.getSelectionModel().select(2);

    playList.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<String>>() {

        public void handle(ListView.EditEvent<String> event) {

            System.out.println(event.getEventType());
            System.out.println(event.getNewValue());
        }
    });

}

class ButtonCell extends ListCell<String> {

    private TextField fieldForEditingCell;

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {

        if (!isEditable() || !getListView().isEditable()) {
            return;
        }

        super.startEdit();

        if (isEditing()) {
            fieldForEditingCell = new TextField("Enter your edit here");
            fieldForEditingCell.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

                public void handle(KeyEvent keyPress) {
                    if (keyPress.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        String nameOfnewPlayList = fieldForEditingCell.getText();
                        observablePlayList.add(nameOfnewPlayList);
                        playList.setItems(null);
                        playList.setItems(observablePlayList);
                        playList.getSelectionModel().select(nameOfnewPlayList);

                    } else if (keyPress.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            });

            setGraphic(fieldForEditingCell);
            fieldForEditingCell.requestFocus();
            fieldForEditingCell.setEditable(true);

            fieldForEditingCell.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    if (!newValue && fieldForEditingCell != null) {
                        commitEdit(fieldForEditingCell.getText());
                    }
                }
            });

            fieldForEditingCell.selectAll();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        ImageView addSymbol;
        addSymbol = ImageViewBuilder.create().image(new Image("/images/ic_add_grey600_15dp.png")).build();
        addSymbol.fitHeightProperty();
        setText(getItem());
        setGraphic(addSymbol);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if ((this.getIndex() == 0) || (this.getIndex() == 1)) {
            ImageView addSymbol;
            addSymbol = ImageViewBuilder.create().image(new Image("/images/ic_add_grey600_15dp.png")).build();
            addSymbol.fitHeightProperty();
            setText(item);
            setGraphic(addSymbol);

            getStyleClass().add("custom_list-cell");
            //setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5F5F5");
            //setStyle("-fx-hover-color: yellow");
        } else {
            setText(item);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }

}
//begin TableViewCell

class playListTableViewCellFactory extends TableCell<String, String> {

}

//begin tableView methods...
public void tableDraggedOVer(DragEvent event) {
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    if (db.hasFiles()) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
    }
    event.consume();

}

public void dropCompleted(DragEvent event) {
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    boolean success = false;

    if (db.hasFiles()) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
        DBUtils.addToPLaylistTableFromDragAndDrop(db.getFiles());
        success = true;
    }

    event.setDropCompleted(success);
    event.consume();
}

}
```

Comment: as is, a TableCell doesn't display anything - you have to implement updateItem to make it do. BTW: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (f.i. classes start with a capital letter)

Comment: Additionally, you don't seem to have set a cell value factory on any of the table columns; and unless you did it in FXML you haven't added the table columns to the table. The "most straightforward" way to display data in a table view is actually to define a "model class", instances of which represent each row of the table. This will make your code much easier. Have a look at the [`TableView` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE), at least through example 13-6, and see if you can work from there. (`Person` is the "model class here.)

Comment: Thanks, James. The table is described out in FXML. When I run the program the the column heads show up properly. I was just having trouble getting the data into the cells. With Kleopatra's advice - I have a rough implementation up and running. I'm currently viewing the tutorial. I'm not sure if the model is appropriate - I could end up having 5000 Object representing files at times. My table view will be getting its data from a JavaDB ResultSet. Could you provide me with any advice on the matter?

Comment: Why would having 5000 objects prevent you from using this approach?

Comment: I assumed having 5000 objects would be resource intensive. I making this program for laptops/PCs.

Comment: It's (almost?) no more resource intensive than storing the data any other way. It's got to sit in memory somehow. Perhaps you add the overhead of a few bytes per object, which would be.. 20-30KB? Even for real data ;) this approach [doesn't seem to be a problem](https://community.oracle.com/message/11066813#11066813)

Comment: Ok! Thanks again, James. I'm still pretty new to programming and was worried about overhead. I'll create a MediaFile class(the JavaFX way), then use the ResultSet to create MediaFile objects which can then be put into a TableView as is done in the tutorial.